# In Android Studio, I'm getting the VT-x and SVM errors regardless of what I do

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio is saying my CPU doesn't support VT-x or SVM, regardless of whether or not I use a virtual device or a real phone. And my Hyper-V thing is also turned on.

My CPU isn't an Intel one I think, because I actually have the hyper v/hardware acccelaration turned on. I remember seeing other answers claiming that a person should use a virtual device if he gets this error. But I'm using I'm doing that and I'm getting the same error - again, regardless of what I do.

Others in different threads have stated that use "armeabi- v7a" or something in the "Other Images" tab when choosing a virtual device, but I still get that error message in the end.

Any help?

Comment: If you are using a real phone, you shouldn't see that message, so you've  done something wrong

Comment: if you have AMD based CPU and  your are using Windows 10 home or single language then visualization is not possible even you enable your SVM mode from Boot menu

Comment: Are there any solutions to the problem? I'm using Windows 10. Do I just have to use/get a different computer that has an intel processor?